# How to execute sumproduct with two criteria?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I need to create a formula in excel that returns the sum-product of two columns in a range, based on two conditions.
Considering a table of 4 columns (A;B;C;D), if any row in column A is equal to a given value (example="A") and any row in column B starts with "*", then multiply column C and D and sum these products.
Any suggestions on how to implement the formula?

I thought it could be the following formula but it doesn't work:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(A2:A12="A"); --(left(B2:B12;1)="*"); C2:C12; D2:D12)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use an [array formula](https://www.vertex42.com/blog/excel-formulas/array-formula-examples.html#:%7E:text=In%20Excel%2C%20an%20Array%20Formula,pressing%20Ctrl%2BShift%2BEnter..) such as :

```
{=SUM((A2:A12="A")*(LEFT(B2:B12)="*")*C2:C12*D2:D12)}
```

Remember to validate with ctrl+shift+enter

Comment: For non O365 users you'd need to CSE this formula (like you said) but that's why `SUMPRODUCT()` is so handy: `=SUMPRODUCT((A2:A12="A")*(LEFT(B2:B12;1)="*")*C2:C12*D2:D12)`